# Changing string to date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I was wondering how I can convert string like dd.mm.yyyy into date format so I can make comparisons among dates.

I first get the date part of string but I can't use STR_TO_DATE function. I think I have to convert this date string into a new date string like dd/mm/yyyy then I can use STR_TO_DATE. Do you have any suggestions?

```
SUBSTR(OLD_VALUE,1,10)
```

**EDIT**

Ok this is what I did so far and I'm getting error

```
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(OLD_VALUE_TEXT),1,10),'%D.%M.%Y') <
      (STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(NEW_VALUE_TEXT),1,10),'%D.%M.%Y'))
```

Both old and new value texts are 40 length char and in this format 01.02.2014

**Sample Data**

I'm sharing soma data sample. I need to find entries that new_value is bigger than old value. Thank you

```
Name Char(30)      Old_Value_Text Char(40)         New_Value_Text Char(40)
John               12.02.2012                      01.02.2014
Max                14.01.2014                      22.02.2014
Carter             05.05.2013                      19.01.2014
James              03.12.1998                      07.02.2013
Hank               26.04.2009                      13.10.2012
```

Comment: As a curiosity, why can't you use `str_to_date`? It would be just what you need...

Comment: STR_TO_DATE is fine just use as arguments the format that you have '%d.%m.%Y'

Comment: Ok I tried however I need to call this function inside 'WHERE' clause

Comment: Post some sample data.

Comment: @Mihai ok I added some data

Comment: @AhmetTanakol Here is a working fiddle..http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afdb3/1 Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Also in your arguments case matters M is not the same with m same for D http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: @Mihai I see thank you mate, as you said my problem was when I run the sql query, the program was converting lower case to upper case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's far from best but you could always try this:

`concat_ws('/',substring(OLD_VALUE,1,2), substring(OLD_VALUE,4,2), substring(OLD_VALUE from 7));`

You can try it on the console:

`SELECT concat_ws('/',substring('dd.mm.yyyy',1,2), substring('dd.mm.yyyy',4,2), substring('dd.mm.yyyy' from 7));`

will return this:

> dd/mm/yyyy